# Relationship does not exist - DRF, Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

использую Postgresql в django

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    courses = models.CharField(verbose_name="доступы")
```

после выполнения

```
py manage.py makemigrations
py manage.py migrate
```

появляется: "ОШИБКА:  отношение "courses_profile" не существует"

Comment: Покажите, список ваших миграций.

Comment: Как мне кажется это только часть моделей, приложите весь код

Comment: я удалил файлы миграций и ошибка ушла